# Click type conversion

Tags: python, command-line-interface, python-click

I am using `click` to define a CLI that takes `datetime`s and a comma seperated list of parameters.

```
import click

def valid_date(s):
    try:
        return dt.strptime(s, "%Y-%m-%d")
    except ValueError:
        msg = "Not a valid date: '{0}'.".format(s)
        raise Exception(msg)
    except TypeError:
        return None

split_parameter = lambda _, __, s: s.split(",")
check_date = lambda _, __, s: valid_date(s)


@click.command()
@click.argument('symbols', callback=split_parameter)
@click.option('--start_date', callback=check_date)
@click.option('--end_date', callback=check_date)
@click.option('--file_name')
def f(symbols, start_date, end_date, file_name):
     return None
```

It works but the logic around `callback`s is a bit awkward. Both splitting the list and converting to `datetime` interrupts the nice simple structure of click. Is there a pythonic way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can encapsulate the ugly `lambda _, __, x` part in a decorator:

```
import click
from datetime import datetime as dt

def click_callback(f):
    return lambda _, __, x: f(x)

def check_date(s):
    try:
        return dt.strptime(s, "%Y-%m-%d")
    except ValueError:
        msg = "Not a valid date: '{0}'.".format(s)
        raise Exception(msg)
    except TypeError:
        return None

@click.command()
@click.argument('symbols', callback=click_callback(lambda s: s.split(',')))
@click.option('--start_date', callback=click_callback(check_date))
@click.option('--end_date', callback=click_callback(check_date))
@click.option('--file_name')
def f(symbols, start_date, end_date, file_name):
    print(symbols, start_date, end_date, file_name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f()
```

Or like this (only the relevant part is shown):

```
def click_callback(f):
    return {'callback': lambda _, __, x: f(x)}

@click.command()           #  vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
@click.argument('symbols',    **click_callback(lambda s: s.split(',')))
@click.option('--start_date', **click_callback(check_date))
@click.option('--end_date',   **click_callback(check_date))
@click.option('--file_name')
def f(symbols, start_date, end_date, file_name):
    print(symbols, start_date, end_date, file_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted the date string in '05-Jul-2018' like format, the following worked for me

```
def check_date(ctx, param, value):
    try:
        _ = dt.strptime(value, "%Y-%m-%d")
        return value
    except ValueError:
        msg = "Not a valid date: '{0}'.".format(value)
        raise Exception(msg)

def getDate():
    return '09-Jul-2018' #you can have any code here

@click.command()
@click.option('--start_date', callback=check_date, default=lambda :getDate())
def f(symbols, start_date):
    print(symbols, start_date)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f()
```

You can find more help [Here](http://click.pocoo.org/5/options/#callbacks-and-eager-options)

Comment: (This post does not seem to [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) the question. Please either edit your answer, or just post it as a comment to the question).