# Missing type parameters for generic type "Callable"

Tags: callback, mypy, python-typing, python-click

What is the correct way to add type hints to the following function?

```py
from typing import Callable

def format_callback(f: Callable) -> Callable:
    """Function to wrap a function to use as a click callback.

    Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/42110044/8056572
    """
    return lambda _, __, x: f(x)
```

Now `mypy` is complaining with `Missing type parameters for generic type "Callable"`

The code needs to be compatible with both Python 3.9 and 3.10. I can use `typing_extensions` if needed.

**Edit:**

The following passes `mypy` but has too many `Any`'s for my taste. Is there a better way?

```py
from typing import Any
from typing import Callable

import click


def format_callback(f: Callable[[Any], Any]) -> Callable[[click.Context, dict[str, Any], Any], Any]:
    """Function to wrap a function to use as a click callback.

    Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/42110044/8056572
    """
    return lambda _, __, x: f(x)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without looking at `click`, the immediate fix you can do is to provide type variables that match `f(x)`:

```py
from typing import Any, Callable, TypeVar

import click

ArgT = TypeVar("ArgT")
ReturnT = TypeVar("ReturnT")

def format_callback(
    f: Callable[[ArgT], ReturnT]
) -> Callable[[click.Context, dict[str, Any], ArgT], ReturnT]:
    return lambda _, __, x: f(x)
```

This will guard you against bad typing in the internal body of `format_callback`.

---

A brief scan of `click` seems to indicate that you want to pass the return value of `format_callback` to one of the following class constructors or their subclass constructors:

- [`click.core.Parameter.__init__::callback`](https://github.com/pallets/click/blob/7586834cab38c5592d9d6de3ee0ebe75d4353bfb/src/click/core.py#L2076):

  ```py
  callback: t.Optional[t.Callable[[Context, "Parameter", t.Any], t.Any]]
  ```
- [`click.core.Command.__init__::callback`](https://github.com/pallets/click/blob/7586834cab38c5592d9d6de3ee0ebe75d4353bfb/src/click/core.py#L1197)

  ```py
  callback: t.Optional[t.Callable[..., t.Any]]
  ```

Now, based on the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42110044) that you linked to, which passes the keyword argument `callback` to [`@click.argument`](https://github.com/pallets/click/blob/7586834cab38c5592d9d6de3ee0ebe75d4353bfb/src/click/decorators.py#L332-L348) and [`@click.option`](https://github.com/pallets/click/blob/7586834cab38c5592d9d6de3ee0ebe75d4353bfb/src/click/decorators.py#L351-L369), it seems like you'd actually want to use `click.core.Parameter.__init__`, because the decorators' fallback classes are [`ArgumentClass = click.core.Argument`](https://github.com/pallets/click/blob/7586834cab38c5592d9d6de3ee0ebe75d4353bfb/src/click/decorators.py#L344) and [`OptionClass = click.core.Option`](https://github.com/pallets/click/blob/7586834cab38c5592d9d6de3ee0ebe75d4353bfb/src/click/decorators.py#L365), respectively, which are [both](https://github.com/pallets/click/blob/7586834cab38c5592d9d6de3ee0ebe75d4353bfb/src/click/core.py#L2943) [subclasses](https://github.com/pallets/click/blob/7586834cab38c5592d9d6de3ee0ebe75d4353bfb/src/click/core.py#L2427) of `click.Core.Parameter`. This means that the second argument to the return `Callable` type cannot be `dict[str, Any]`, according to the type annotation for `click.core.Parameter.__init__::callback`. Then, you really should have this instead:

```py
def format_callback(
    f: Callable[[ArgT], ReturnT]
) -> Callable[[click.Context, click.Parameter, ArgT], ReturnT]:
    return lambda _, __, x: f(x)
```

---

Since you're discarding `click.Context` and `click.Parameter` as `_, __` in your `lambda`, providing these are only for documentation purposes, of course. They could easily be `object, object` instead.

Comment: Also consider using [ParamSpec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.ParamSpec) instead of TypeVar for `ArgT`.